# Can I say 'drop off the laundry'?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I've heard people say *dropping off the dry cleaning* to mean take the clothes that need dry cleaning to a dry cleaner's. Can I use *drop off the laundry* to mean taking the laundry to staffed laundries? If not, what is the common way to refer to this household chore?

Comment: Certainly - there's nothing particularly unusual about this. What's more remarkable is that you found a staffed laundry service that's _not_ dry-cleaning.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin Thanks. I always give it a search first and when I get frustrated, I post it here and seek an English native speaker's opinion on that. So we can say this.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  I've found that some coin laundry places also have bulk laundry services, if you don't want to do your own.  No idea of how reliable they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can "drop off" almost anything, if it involves going someplace and leaving something.

> I'm going to **drop off the kids** at school.
>
> I need to **drop off my car** at the mechanic.  Something's wrong with the engine.
>
> Let me first **drop off these reports** at the office, then I'll join you for happy hour.

The challenge is context.  As Jeff Zeitlin points out, it should make sense to the listener -- for example, here in California, I've never really heard of anyone who would "drop off laundry" that wasn't dry cleaning.  Either you do it yourself at a laundromat, or you have your own machines.  It certainly makes sense, but it's unusual enough that I'd have to think about what you mean.

The exception is at hotels that offer laundry services, but in this case you wouldn't need to *drop off* the laundry, but rather have housekeeping come by to *pick it up* from your room.

> Hi, this is Room 404.  Could you send housekeeping by to **pick up** my laundry?  Thanks.

Comment: Where I come from, there are places offering all types of laundry services at once. You just need to _drop off your laundry there_ (now I can say it with confidence lol). They do the washing, ironing, the stains you get the idea. Thanks Andrew.